# How to count the number of words in a Contenteditable div in real time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="text" id="text" contenteditable="true"></div>

<div class="words"></div>
```

Whenever the user types into the `div` 'text', how would I make it so that the number of **words** entered get displayed into the `div` 'words'.

I want this to be in real time - no page refreshing.

I,e.

```
<div class="text" id="text" contenteditable="true">Hello world!</div>

<div class="words">2</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could listen to the `input` event of the `contenteditable` element and then split the text and output the length of the array:

- `.trim()` removes whitespace at the beginning/end of the string.
- `.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')` removes consecutive whitespace so that it isn't counted as an additional word.
- `.split(' ')` splits the string at the whitespace so that the count can be retrieved.

As [Andreas points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28617680/how-to-count-the-number-of-words-in-a-contenteditable-div-in-real-time/28617791#comment45538902_28617791) in the comments, you could also split/match the text using [word boundaries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) (`/\b/`) so that entities like dashes are excluded.

```js
$('#text').on('input', function () {
    var text = this.textContent,
        count = text.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' ').length;
    
    $('.words').text(count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text" id="text" contenteditable="true">Text</div>
<div class="words"></div>
```

Without jQuery:

```js
document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('input', function () {
    var text = this.textContent,
        count = text.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' ').length;
    
    document.querySelector('.words').textContent = count;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text" id="text" contenteditable="true">Text</div>
<div class="words"></div>
```

Comment: Unless `- - - - -` should be counted as five words I would go with `count = text.match(/\b/g).length / 2` - http://jsfiddle.net/5v6wuumd/

Answer (score 0):

This will do it...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#text").keyup(function(){

      var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
      var num = text.split(" ").length;
      $(".words").html(text);

    });
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly, just `$(".words").html(text);` has to become `$(".words").html(num);`

Comment: This doesn't work if there is consecutive whitespace.